# How to remove first slash in href - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How to remove the first slash that appearing in href, here is the generated HTML:

```
<div id="site-navigation">
  <a href="/#about-us">About Us</a>
  <a href="/#contact-us">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery that I am using to archive the result but fails :(

```
jQuery('#site-navigation a').each(function(){
  jQuery(this).attr('href').replace(/\/$/, '')
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use jQuery's [attribute value starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector `a[href^="/"]` selects all the anchors whose `href` attribute values starts with `/`. If all the anchors starts with `/` you can skip the attribute-value selector.
2. Use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)/[`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function) method with the function callback to update the attribute value
3. Use [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) method to return the string without the starting `/`

Code:

```
jQuery('#site-navigation a[href^="/"]').attr('href', function (i, oldHref) {
    return oldHref.substr(1);
});
```

Comment: that was really helpful, thanks. Can you please tell me if I need to  add '/' at the starting how to do it.

Comment: @Syed Similar as above 1. The selector should be simple without the starts with selector 2. Use `return '/' + oldHref;`

Comment: how do you remove last slash

Comment: @computerguy You can use regex with replace as `.replace(/\$/, '');` but note that this does not update the string, you've to assign the result to the string.